# Java scene builder scene changing, different packages

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm dealing with JavaFX scene builder. My problem is, that I can't find out how to change scenes when fxml file of scene is in another package. I think I have to get back in directory path, but I have no idea how to do it in Java (something like ../ in location string is not working here).

So, how I can get back in directory path, or how in any other way I can change my scenes without putting them all into one package?

P.S. I have to change scene and later get back to previous one.

My method for scene changing:

```
 public void sceneLoader(ActionEvent event, String path) throws IOException {
        Parent startPageParent1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(path));
        Scene startPageScene1 = new Scene(startPageParent1);
        Stage appStage1 = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        appStage1.setScene(startPageScene1);
        appStage1.show();
    }
```

And how I'm trying to do, though, works only when I transfer second xfml file into the same package and delete package name from location string(when it is like "FXMLAddGroup.fxml" but not like "otherWindows/FXMLAddGroup.fxml") Though I have many fxml files and I want to divide them into separate packages:

```
    addGroup.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event){ 
                try{sceneLoader(event, "otherWindows/FXMLAddGroup.fxml");
                    }
                catch(IOException ex){
                    System.out.println("Error: can not open the addGroup window");
                    }
                }
            });
```

[photo of my packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4aBd.png)

Comment: You should add in an example of your project heirarchy so we can more clearly see your problem.

Comment: Thank you for advice, not sure if it's the best way, I added a photo of my packages

Comment: There are no classes in the default package, which means the relative path is wrong. Specify the full path from the root: `/otherWindows/FXMLAddGroup.fxml`. BTW: the convention is to use only lower case letters for package names.

Comment: @fabian Thank you! Sorry, for upper case l;etters, I am quite new in OOP :/